# Get stored Wi-Fi passwords from non-rooted device

Tags: android, passwords, wifi

Is there any way to get stored wifi passwords from not rooted device? I will provide a backup and share option within our app.

Comment: I would be very surprised if there was. Most API's will not return wifi passwords. Android's own WifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks() does this as well. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#getConfiguredNetworks()

Comment: I sure hope not, for obvious security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API support for reading/writing WiFi passwords for APKs not signed with the system key. So you won't be able to retrieve it.